# jQuery insertAfter: will insert <li> but not <a>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="routelist" data-theme="g">
<li id="firstlistitem" style="display:none;">
```

```
$("<li><a href='http://www.google.co.uk'></a></li>").text('content').insertAfter($("#firstlistitem"));
```

and see also this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6MW2e/

How come I end up with an unlinked list item? How can I insert an element with a link?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're setting the text of the outer element (the `<li>`) and not the inner element (the link).

If you're going to keep that syntax, you could try:

```
$('<li></li>')
    .append(
        $('<a href="www.google.co.uk"></a>').text('content'))
    .insertAfter($('#firstlistitem'));
```

It seems to me that it would be much cleaner if you simply did:

```
$('<li><a href="www.google.co.uk">' + content + '</a></li>')
    .insertAfter($('#firstlistitem'));
```

Comment: +1, looks like the link is getting wiped out because he's calling text('content') on the li

Answer (score 0):

Your overwriting the text of the `<li>` when you call `.text("content")`

```
$("<li/>", {
    html: $("<a/>", { href: "http://www.google.co.uk", text: content })
}).appendTo("#routelist");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/6MW2e/5/